# T-SQL stored procedure result into variable

Tags: json, t-sql, stored-procedures, return-value, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure for some selection in JSON.

```
CREATE PROC [pr_MySP]
    -- params
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
...
    FOR JSON PATH;
END
```

And now I want to use this stored procedure in another.

```
CREATE PROC [pr_MySP_1]
    -- params
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result_sp NVARCHAR(MAX);
    EXEC @result_sp = [pr_MySP];
    SELECT @result_sp;
END
```

But when I try `SELECT @result_sp;` it return 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can return the json from `pr_MySP` as an output parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what else you are doing within your first SP, but this might be better solved within an inlineable UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateJSON()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sys.objects FOR JSON AUTO);
END
GO
```

--You can use the UDF in any context. You can define parameters to control the behaviour

```
DECLARE @TheJson NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @TheJson=dbo.CreateJSON();
SELECT @TheJson;
GO
```

--Clean up

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CreateJSON;
```

In most cases an *inline TVF* is better in performance! But you'd have to *join* its resultset, which is not so intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in `table variable` instead.

```
DECLARE @result_sp (results NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @result_sp
EXEC [pr_MySP]

SELECT TOP 1 results FROM @result_sp
```

and if you still wanted it to store in a normal variable,

```
DECLARE @final NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result_sp (results NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @result_sp
EXEC [pr_MySP]

SELECT TOP 1 @final = results FROM @result_sp

SELECT @final
```

Comment: But in pr_MySp I use "FOR JSON" which cannot be used in INSERT operator

Comment: the code should be in the second procedure not within the first

Comment: I understand it. But when I try to do INSERT INTO result_sp
EXEC result_sp = [pr_MySP] it failed with error "The FOR JSON clause is not allowed in the "INSERT" statement"

Comment: @OlegVolkov, sorry there was a typo in the answer. please see the update.